# Adding a property to an association

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

Having two tables Courses and Employees, i have a many to many relationship between the two. EF automatically generates an intermediary table called CoursesEmployees.
I want to add a property IsPassed to that intermediary.

I could do this in **MySQL** but i won't know where to map it to in my data model. Is it possible? Preferably in the data model because **i work model-first**.

I use all of the latest versions.

Comment: are you using an .edmx file?

Comment: Are you doing Code First, Model First, or Database First? The answer will depend on which approach you're using.

Comment: I am using a .edmx file yes, and also work model-first. I stated that in the post ;-p

Comment: Couldn't you just explicitly define the link table in your model instead of letting EF create it automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to achieve what you want in a Model First approach is to explicitly model the relation table and add your `IsPassed`property to it, as I've done below. There is a 1-to-m relationship between Course and Course_Employee entities as well as a 1-to-n relationship between Employee and Course_Employee entities. The combination of the two one-to-many relationships creates the many-to-many relationship between Course and Employee entities.

[image]

Comment: Any reason to not go with a composite pk on the relation table foregoing the `Id` column?

Comment: Of course you could/would use a composite PK; I was just throwing something together quickly at work to illustrate my answer.

Comment: @grin0048 Nonetheless you brought out the perfectionist in me so I've updated the model :)

Comment: Thanks i will try this. Although the following text in visual studio confused my to thinking it would require to be many-to-many relationships:
CourseEmployee can have 1 (One) instance of Employee. Use CourseEmployee.Employee to access the Employee instance.

Comment: Well, each Course_Employee instance holds the association for exactly one Employee and exactly one Course, which is what you want (otherwise your IsPassed property is meaningless). If you want to get all employees in a course you would just use something like: `course.Course_Employees.SelectMany(ce => ce.Employee)`